# Exchange export script not writing to individual pst files

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to export disabled usermailboxes, names starting with 'a', from Exchange with the following script. 
If I run it without pipe or with -whatif everything is fine, if I run it life, the batch job tries to write to the same .pst file.

I'm certainly no Powershell expert, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

```
Get-Mailbox -filter "recipienttype -eq 'usermailbox' -and exchangeuseraccountcontrol -eq 'accountdisabled' -and name -like 'a*'" | new-mailboxexportrequest -file path ("\\server\share\exportfolder\$_.pst")
```

cheers

Comment: Try this: `Get-Mailbox -filter "recipienttype -eq 'usermailbox' -and exchangeuseraccountcontrol -eq 'accountdisabled' -and name -like 'a*'" | % { new-mailboxexportrequest -file path ("\\server\share\exportfolder\$($_.UserPrincipalName).pst") }` (added ForEach and UPN in name)

Comment: Splendid - will try this asap.

Comment: You also need to delete a space between `file` and `path` - just noticed that

Comment: Ah thanks, yes. Bad revision control. I got that error eliminated earlier but I came back in posting my question here.

Comment: I get a prompt for input now:

_cmdlet New-MailboxExportRequest at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Mailbox:_

Comment: So you have to do what you're being asked for: supply value for `Mailbox` like this `-Mailbox $_.Identity`

Comment: thank you, this works now

    Get-Mailbox -filter "recipienttype -eq 'usermailbox' -and exchangeuseraccountcontrol -eq 'accountdisabled' -and name -like 'a*'" | % { new-mailboxexportrequest -Mailbox $_.Identity -filepath ("\\server\share\exportfolder\$($_.UserPrincipalName).pst") }

Comment: Glad to hear that, let me convert it to an answer so you can accept it if you don't mind.

Comment: sure, go ahead 
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal using this:

```
Get-Mailbox -filter "recipienttype -eq 'usermailbox' -and exchangeuseraccountcontrol -eq 'accountdisabled' -and name -like 'a*'" `
| ForEach-Object `
{ new-mailboxexportrequest -Mailbox $_.Identity -filepath ("\\server\share\exportfolder\$($_.UserPrincipalName).pst") }
```

*(Line breaks added for better readability)*

#### Explanation:

In your code you were using `$_` which in this example was array of mailbox objects. However, `new-mailboxexportrequest` expected `String` value for `-FilePath` parameter. That's why `$($_.UserPrincipalName)` is needed.

First dollar sign and brackets added so you can access property value between the double quotes.

At the end, to iterate through all the array elements you can use `ForEach-Object` (or just `%` which is its alias).

Comment: ...-Mailbox $_.Identity is missing